# How can I test my Grails service save method?

Tags: grails, spock

I've created Grails service using `grails create-service TaskCRUDService`. That command created files `TaskCRUDService.groovy` in `grails-app\services` and `TaskCRUDServiceSpec.groovy` in `test\unit` folder.

The only method in my `TaskCRUDService` is

```
Task save(String name) {
    Task task = new Task()
    task.name = name

    task.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
}
```

I wanted to test this method so, I've filled the body of "test something" method generated by the Grails in the test class. So this is my `TaskCRUDServiceSpec` code:

```
@TestFor(TaskCRUDService)
class TaskCRUDServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        when:
            Task t = service.save('task name')
        then:
            assert t.name == 'task name'
    }
}
```

But the test doesn't work.  When I run `grails test-app` I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [Task] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
        at TaskCRUDService.$tt__save(TaskCRUDService.groovy:29)
        at TaskCRUDServiceSpec.test create(TaskCRUDServiceSpec.groovy:24)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like it should work, but even if it did, it's a bad test. Never use unit tests for testing persistence. Use an integration test so you're using a real database and not just the in-memory GORM implementation that uses a ConcurrentHashMap to store the data.